# Python - insert HTML content tp WordPress using xmlrpc api

Tags: python, wordpress, beautifulsoup, xml-rpc

I'm trying to insert HTML content in my WordPress blog via XMLRPC but if i insert HTML - i got an error:

> raise TypeError, "cannot marshal %s objects" % type(value) TypeError:
>   cannot marshal  objects

If i use bleach (for clean tags) - i got text with tags on my page

My code

```
# coding: utf-8
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bleach
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts


xmlrpc_url = "http://site.ru/xmlrpc.php"
wp_username = "user"
wp_password = "123"
blog_id = ""
client = Client(xmlrpc_url, wp_username, wp_password, blog_id)

url = "https://lifehacker.ru/2016/08/30/finansovye-sovety-dlya-molodyx-par/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

post_title = soup.find("h1")
post_excerpt = soup.find("div", {"class", "single__excerpt"})
for tag in post_excerpt():
    for attribute in ["class", "id", "style"]: 
        del tag[attribute]
post_content = soup.find("div", {"class","post-content"})
for tag in post_content():
    for attribute in ["class", "id", "style"]:
        del tag[attribute]

post = WordPressPost()
post.title = post_title.text
post.content = post_content
post.id = client.call(posts.NewPost(post))

post.post_status = 'publish'
client.call(posts.EditPost(post.id, post))
```

How i can insert parsed HTML content in my WordPress blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .replace after bleach and fixed issue.

My code

```
...
post_content_insert = bleach.clean(post_content)

post_content_insert = post_content_insert.replace('&lt;','<')
post_content_insert = post_content_insert.replace('&gt;','>')


post = WordPressPost()
post.title = post_title.text
post.content = post_content_insert
post.id = client.call(posts.NewPost(post))
```